# Django Rest Framework app, served by Gunicorn, proxied by Nginx (SSL)

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

Goal: I want to serve django-rest-framework(drf) responses over https.

I'm trying to understand why my setup isn't working, whether it can be fixed by a simple settings change in one of the components, or if I should try a different approach.

I have a drf application served by gunicorn. Gunicorn is behind an NGINX proxy. I also have some static content served by NGINX. This setup has worked fine for plain old http.

Then I set NGINX to listen over ssl (,and installed certs, etc.). The static content works over https. I can still get to drf via http, but I get nothing / timed out over https. The gunicorn logs haven't been that helpful to me, but django dev server gives "dev server doesn't work over https" when sent a request.

Here is my first attempt at the nginx config (anonymized). This was mostly from reading the [gunicorn](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html) and nginx manuals.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ...

    location /static/{
        alias /path/to/static/content/;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 $scheme://example.com/static;
    }

    location /drf/{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;            
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:6565; # bound to gunicorn, can be reached from http://example.com:6565 - ideally want to be available from https://example.com:6565 
    }        
}

server { 
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com
}
```

I don't *think* there is an additional step for gunicorn. On the DRF side, I read the [relevant Django security section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/security/#ssl-https) and tried using the `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` = True (new in 1.8 - not addressed in a lot of existing questions) and `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`.

I also tried with a redirect, but this was sort of a shot in the dark:

```
 ...after `proxy_pass` above, and commenting out proxy_redirect off:
 proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:6565 https://example.com/drf
```

Ubuntu 14, Gunicorn 19, Nginx 1.1,
Django 1.8 (DRF 3.2)

Update:
NGINX Error logging:
I get nothing if I go to `https://example.com:6565`. Here is an error from nginx's error log for a request to `https://example.com/drf/endpoint`.

```
2015/09/08 13:53:52 [error] 12564#0: *14 connect() failed (111: Connection refused while connecting to upstream, client: 155.xxx.xxx.xx, server:example.com, request:"GET /drf/endpoint", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6565/drf/endpoint", host: "example.com"
```

Comment: Can you post more error related details?

Comment: Where is your `/default/home` location config?

Comment: @RohitJain that should have just been /static for the example.

Comment: @seenus I added an NGINX error_log. Let me know if you're looking for something else.

Comment: I might as well mention that your header setting is incomplete, you aren't using the full name

Comment: And you appear to be getting a timeout from gunicorn, are you sure it is running and bound to that port?

Comment: @KevinBrown I believe it is running and bound to that port because I can reach it at http://example.com:6565. Re: the header settings: I'll go back and revisit the gunicorn and nginx docs soon, but any recommended reading appreciated.

Comment: The header setting comment was that `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` should be set to `('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')` for your configuration.

Comment: Are your API responses taking longer than 20 seconds to return? Something is timing out which is causing issues here. Also, you want to use `proxy_pass` not `proxy_redirect` here.